# What is the first game I should Develop?

Tags: javascript

What is the first game every developer should develop?

Comment: I started off with a simple text based rpg. Just start off simple and go from there.

Comment: Please see the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about these types of questions. "Where do I get started" questions are discouraged here because they are not constructive.

Answer (score 5):

The [Guess the Number game](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Guess_the_number).

Answer (score 3):

One that they finish............